# SQL Is it possible to replace values in a Rollup?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, null, group-by, rollup

I have a result set that mainly consists of columns of values. However, the left most column contains text which I'm using to effectively label each row. When I ROLLUP, the values total, which is great. The text in my 'No KS2' column rolls up to a NULL which is expected. Is there anything I can do to replace the NULL with text eg 'Total'?

All the NULLs in the other columns should be there and I don't need to replace those.

Here's an example of my results set eg:

```
No KS2    6c/D-    6b/D     6a/D+
2a        1        NULL     NULL     
3c        3        NULL     NULL     
3b        NULL     5        NULL
3a        NULL     NULL     6
NULL      4        5        6
```

Here's what I'd like to do:

```
No KS2    6c/D-    6b/D     6a/D+
2a        1        NULL     NULL     
3c        3        NULL     NULL     
3b        NULL     5        NULL
3a        NULL     NULL     6
Total     4        5        6
```

EDIT:

When generating the KS2 column results set using the group by I have already replace NULL values with 'No KS2'. Please see my GROUP BY code below:

```
GROUP BY
       CASE Name
            WHEN 'English' THEN
                CASE WHEN [Ks2en] IS NULL OR [Ks2en]='' THEN
                    'No KS2'
                WHEN [Ks2en] IN ('1a','1b','1c') THEN 
                    '1'
                ELSE
                    [Ks2en]
                END
            WHEN 'Mathematics' THEN
                CASE WHEN [Ks2ma] IS NULL OR [Ks2ma]='' THEN
                    'No KS2'
                WHEN [Ks2ma] IN ('1a','1b','1c') THEN 
                    '1'
                ELSE
                    [Ks2ma]
                END
            ELSE
                CASE WHEN [Ks2av] IS NULL OR [Ks2av]='' THEN
                    'No KS2'
                WHEN [Ks2av] IN ('1a','1b','1c') THEN 
                    '1'
                ELSE
                    [Ks2av]
                END
            END 
            WITH ROLLUP
```

EDIT: This isn't a duplicate as the solution to the question that this is supposed to be a duplicate of does not resolve my issue. I edited the code to explain the difference. I already have a case statement that replaces out my NULL values in the KS2 column with 'No KS2'.

Comment: Yes, along the right lines. However, I already have a case statement that replaces out my NULL values in the KS2 column with 'No KS2'. I'll post my GROUP BY code.

Comment: Encase the whole lot in parenthesis and create a select statement which replaces the NULL. select * FROM (<your full query>) data

Comment: Regarding your edit. It **is** a duplicate. The correct way of replacing `ROLLUP` values is to use the `GROUPING` function. Using `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` will incorrectly apply the total label to groups where the grouping value is `NULL` as well. As you haven't bothered supplying a SQL Fiddle I won't bother showing you how to apply `GROUPING` to your situation (code too long for a comment and I certainly have no interest in setting up a Fiddle from scratch)

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks for taking the time to comment. In future I will try and include an SQL Fiddle. Never done it before, so thanks for pointing it out. It's disappointing you aren't interested in helping a novice, but I understand if it'll will put you out. If you change your mind and find the time I am more than happy to mark as an answer one that utilises grouping rather than my hackjob.

Comment: The question is closed anyway so I can't supply an answer but one way of doing it would be to simply use `CASE WHEN GROUPING(/*Paste your long CASE expression here*/) = 1 THEN 'Total' ELSE /*Paste your long CASE expression here*/ END` but to avoid repeating the long case expression twice in the `SELECT` and once in the `GROUP BY` I would use a CTE or derived table that defines it once then reference that in the `GROUP BY` and `GROUPING` function.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out it was straightforward. The user who posted the comment about investigating COALESCE() and then deleted it sent me on the right track. I wrapped my case statement for the column in the function and my results set displays exactly how I wanted it. So thank you, whoever you were.

```
SELECT 
       COALESCE(CASE Name
            WHEN 'English' THEN
                CASE WHEN                   
                [Ks2en] IS NULL OR [Ks2en]='' THEN
                    'No KS2'
                WHEN [Ks2en] IN ('1a','1b','1c') THEN
                    '1'
                ELSE
                    [Ks2en]
                END
            WHEN 'Mathematics' THEN
                CASE WHEN [Ks2ma] IS NULL OR [Ks2ma]='' THEN
                    'No KS2'
                WHEN [Ks2ma] IN ('1a','1b','1c') THEN
                    '1'
                ELSE
                    [Ks2ma]
                END
            ELSE
                CASE WHEN [Ks2av] IS NULL OR [Ks2av]='' THEN
                    'No KS2'
                WHEN [Ks2av] IN ('1a','1b','1c') THEN
                    '1'
                ELSE
                    [Ks2av]
                END
            END,'Total') AS KS2,...
```